# Drawer navigation is causing my app not to load reanimated dependancy issue (React-Native 0.69.12)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

Initially my app was loading well but I could not get the drawer navigation to show. I searched online and some solutions required that I made some entries in `/android/build.gradle` and `/android/app/build.gradle` also included `/android/app/main/java/com/uber/MainApplication.java`

The drawer did not show and also give me error like symbol not found and some others. I will not be able to reproduce those errors but as at now I have removed all those lines o added to my project and back to how its supposed not to show the drawer but run the project ok.

I have gotten two errors in my metro console, they are

> ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNativeReanimated.default.Value(0)')

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

> ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
> This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

I can't find any help to address that and very fraustrated. Any snippet you request I will provide because I don't know which of codes need to help fix this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So The was an issue of the versioning i was using. First my project is react-native@0.69. And this is so because I am following a tutorial made in JavaScript and i will waste time trying to go the way or JavaScript. It appears the project itself was older than 0.69 and I guess me trying to use the same versions of packages they used was the issue. I check react-native-navigation and they said nothing about compatibility issue with 5.x.

I am now using current versions of stack,drawer and long with all other dependencies and it worked well.